# spring @transactional preformance

Tags: java, performance, spring, transactional

lets say i have a service bean that has 2 methods:

```
@Transactional(readonly=false)
public void doSomething() 

@Transactional(readonly=true)
public void doSomethingReadOnly()
```

and 2 variations of a 3rd method:

```
@Transactional(readonly=false)
public void doSomethingNice1(){
    doSomethingReadOnly();
}

@Transactional(readonly=false)
public void doSomethingNice2(){
    doSomething();
}
```

what call will preform more efficiently? doSomethingNice1()? doSomethingNice2()?

thanks

Comment: The `(readonly=false)` of `doSomethingNice1()` overrides the `(readonly=true)` of `doSomethingReadOnly()` if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

By other words you would like to know whether annotation `@Transactional` makes sense when method annotated with this annotation is called from within the same bean.

I believe that this depends on how your aspects are configured. If they are using proxy the method called from within the same bean will be called directly and therefore the annotation will not do anything. If however you are using byte code modification (e.g. AspectJ) the "strongest" annotation will be used and therefore calling read only transactional method will be *slightly* more efficient.